# distinctUntilChanged in viewmodel not returning newly fetched data

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin, android-architecture-components, android-viewmodel

I'm working with a simple searchview that when I submit a new string to search at my endpoint it should return a different list, instead , when I change that string it will not return the new requested list, instead it just returns the same one that I have fetched first

### View

```
 override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        setupRecyclerView()
        setupSearchView()
        setupDefaultTragosList()
    }

    private fun setupDefaultTragosList(){
        viewModel.setTrago("margarita")
        viewModel.fetchTragosList.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer { result ->
            when(result){
                is Resource.Loading -> {
                    progressBar.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                }
                is Resource.Success -> {
                    progressBar.visibility = View.GONE
                    rv_tragos.adapter = MainAdapter(requireContext(),result.data,this)
                }
                is Resource.Failure -> {
                    progressBar.visibility = View.GONE
                    Log.e("MainFragment", "onRetrofitRequest: ${result.exception}")
                }
            }
        })
    }

    private fun setupSearchView(){
        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(object:androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView.OnQueryTextListener{

            override fun onQueryTextSubmit(query: String?): Boolean {
                viewModel.setTrago(query!!)
                return false
            }

            override fun onQueryTextChange(newText: String?): Boolean {return false}
        })
    }
```

### ViewModel

```
class MainViewModel(private val repo:Repo):ViewModel(){

    private val tragoNameData = MutableLiveData<String>()

    fun setTrago(tragoName:String){
        tragoNameData.value = tragoName
    }

    val fetchTragosList = tragoNameData.distinctUntilChanged().switchMap { tragoName ->
        liveData(Dispatchers.IO) {
            emit(Resource.Loading())
            try{
                emit(repo.getTragosList(tragoName))
            }catch (e: Exception){
                emit(Resource.Failure(e))
            }
        }
    }
}
```

it seems like distinctUntilChange is not refetching my endpoint for the newly searched drink, instead it always returns margarita list of drinks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With some external tech support, the answer was that

> ```
> interface WebService { 
>     @GET("search.php?s=")
>     suspend fun getTragoByName(@Query("tragoName") tragoName:String): DrinkList
>
>     @GET("filter.php?a=")
>     suspend fun getAlcoholicDrink(@Query("alcoholicOrNot") alcoholicOrNot:String): DrinkList
> }
> ```

Should have been

```
interface WebService {
    @GET("search.php")
    suspend fun getTragoByName(@Query("s") tragoName:String): DrinkList

    @GET("filter.php")
    suspend fun getAlcoholicDrink(@Query("a") alcoholicOrNot:String): DrinkList
}
```